# Корень в слове преисподняя

Tags: морфемика

Какой корень в слове преисподняя?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исторический (диахронический) корень тут предположительно "**под**", этот же "под" - в современном предлоге (под чем?) и названии части печного устройства - "под" или "под**и**на" (от которого подовый хлеб, пироги). Но это очень древняя история. Сейчас этот корень выделяют очень редко, только в специальных целях.

Современный (синхронический) - **испод**, он же есть в "исподнем" (белье).

Школьные словари могут трактовать "преиспод" как самостоятельный корень, ибо семантические связи с родственными словами во многом утеряны и сложны для учащихся. Но тут возникает вопрос, а куда девать суффиксальное "Н", и его тоже млоошут записать в корень - это уже от подхода зависит.

Answer (score 2):

**Короткий ответ:** `-преиспо́дн-`

**Длинный ответ:**

Это заимствованное из старославянского языка слово являлось изначально прилагательным `пръисподьнии` и имело значение – "находящийся в самом низу" (вспомним, кстати, исподнее – "нижнее белье"); названное прилагательное было произведено с помощью приставки `пръ-` от прилагательного `исподьнии` – "нижний" от `исподъ` – "низ". *(Источник: Этимологический словарь Крылова)*

---

Но со временем слово устарело и, за неимением ни приставки `пръ-`, ни корня `-исподъ-`, его корень трансформировался в `-преиспо́дн-`

Answer (score -1):

Преисподний = нижний, низменный, очень низкий, подземный (Втор. 32. 28) «Преисподняя земли — так говорят иногда означает утробу матернюю, в коей младенец носим бывает.» (Псал. 138.15)

Получается, что корень в этом слове с тремя приставками представлен одной *Н*.

Comment: А возможно ли считать Н суффиксом,а слово преисподняя - словом без корня?

Comment: Под - не приставка. Это корневой морф.

Comment: Слово, которое — почти олицетворение корня, без корня?